# What's the difference between chat-enabled and chat-driven?

Tags: notebooks, chatai

I opened one of each and they seem identical to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting that ChatGPT would have an opinion about this given that its training data is still back in 2021, I think. ;-)

So...

Chat Enabled: The default cell is an Input Cell and the default Persona is CodeAssistant.

Chat Driven: The default cell is a ChatInput cell and the default Persona is PlainChat.

You can, of course, change the persona in each case if you wish.
Remember that PlainChat does not have access to the WolframLanguageEvaluator tool and so will not execute code for you. Also, when asked to write code, PlainChat will not assume that you want Wolfram Language code. PlainChat is simply a dialog with the LLM with several of the Wolfram Language chatbook hooks unhooked.

So the key difference is in the default interaction with the LLM in the Chatbook and what sort of default new cellstyle the cell will be if you just start typing.

Comment: Note that this is covered in Theo Gray's "Chat Notebooks bring the power of Notebooks to LLMs" (https://www.youtube.com/live/e11ePElnqRE?si=jPPlNbVN-lDMKsVS&t=2085)

Answer (score 3):

Asking in a chat notebook the question:

> What's the difference between chat-enabled and chat-driven notebook in Mathematica?

I get:

> In Mathematica, a "chat-enabled notebook" refers to a notebook that allows for interactive communication with the Wolfram Language kernel. This means that you can run code and receive immediate results, similar to running code in a regular notebook.

> On the other hand, a "chat-driven notebook" takes this interactivity a step further. It allows you to have a back-and-forth conversation with the kernel, where you can ask questions or give commands using natural language. The notebook interprets your input and executes the appropriate code.

> Essentially, a chat-driven notebook provides a more conversational and interactive environment for working with the Wolfram Language. It can be useful for learning and exploration, as well as for creating dynamic and interactive documents.

[image]

Comment: Too funny - didn't occur to me to ask chatGPT myself :-)

Comment: It did not occur to me immediately to ask in a WL chatbook that question... My first thought was to try to find relevant statements in [Stephen Wolfram's article on chatbooks](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2023/06/introducing-chat-notebooks-integrating-llms-into-the-notebook-paradigm/) or [Theo Gray's movie on chatbooks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e11ePElnqRE). Then I got lazy to do all that...